# Is replaceWith supposed to render html as text?

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I have inline JavaScript where I try to use jQuery to replace a div with another div when a button has been pressed.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    attachChangeEvent = setInterval(function(){
        if($("#changeThis").length == 1){
            clearInterval(attachChangeEvent);
            $("#changeText").click(function(){
                $("#changeThis").replaceWith("<div><em>Text Replaced</em></div>");
            });
        }
    }, 100);
</script>
<button id="changeText">click me</button>

<div id="changeThis">Replace this div here</div>
```

I thought it would replace it so it would look like:

Text Replaced

but instead renders as:

```
<div>Text Replaced</div>
```

I've followed several examples, but I don't quite get what I'm doing wrong.
I apologize this was asked, but I didn't understand.

The version of jQuery the site I'm using is 1.12.4

Comment: The samples on [.replaceWIth()](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) show it using HTML in the string

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy paste error when I was trying to fix what I pasted.  I didn't have the "#" in my div and button.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code as provided, as confirmed with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0qwtrpb4/

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet -  can you update it so that it demonstrates the problem?  As provided, it works fine.  Perhaps you have some other `<script src=` that's messing with `.replaceWith`?

Comment: I think I may have found the problem.  I apologize for not providing context, but its for a portlet I'm working on a plone site, and I think it might be a security issue. My template's file looks literally like what I posted and alert, console.log, setInterval were working, so I thought it wouldn't matter.

I did update my code, but the jquery source was causing a conflict.  The site itself is using 1.12.4.  I'll update my question to include the version of jquery.  I think its a Plone issue, in which case I apologize.  If I find its not a security issue, I'll share.

Comment: Sometimes the version of jquery has an impact (eg bind vs on).  I've updated the snippet to 1.12.4 just in case.